# Analytical Solution of Sound Wave Propagation in Moving Medium (1-D Problem)

Tags: fft, sound

I am trying to use frequency-wavenumber analysis to estimate sound wave propagation in a moving medium (fluid). I need to test the technique on analytical data. I wonder if there is an analytical solution that estimates sound wave propagation from a point source in a flowing fluid.  I am assuming a simple problem with the following assumptions:

- Fluid flow is one-dimensional.
- Fluid motion is uniform.
- Fluid is extending to infinity in both sides (i.e., boundary effects are negligible).
- Sound source is a point-source (i.e., sound source does not affect fluid flow)

I am looking for 1D solution that can estimate acousic wave amplitude as function of space (x) and time (t). I think the solution should be identical to point source which is moving in a static fluid.

Comment: That's probably a better fit for https://physics.stackexchange.com/. I would suggest adding a lot more detail. How is the pipe terminated? Is the fluid motion uniform or does it interact with the pipe walls. In the simplest case you can indeed solve this in either frame of reference (static fluid or static source) and suitably far away from the source you will get a plane wave with a Doppler effect on top. The near field of point source in a pipe is fairly complicated.

Comment: @Hilmar I aded some details. I am looking for analytical solution to sound wave propagation in movimg medium.